# Sum products of named columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How do I sum all products of the columns in table with another table?

To make it more clear, look at the image attached. I want the column `Cost` of table `TableA` to be equal to

```
=sum([A]*Lookup([[A];[#Headers]]; Parameters[What]; Parameters[Cost]); ....)
```

And so on for every column of `TableA`.

I am however pretty much reluctant of doing it manually and trying to come up with formula to make it automatically, so if I add another column I don't have to modify the formula in column `Cost`

[image]

**EDIT**

What I have come up so far is something like this:

```
=sum(
    [A]*Lookup([[A];[#Headers]]; Parameters[What]; Parameters[Cost]);
    [B]*Lookup([[B];[#Headers]]; Parameters[What]; Parameters[Cost]);
    [C]*Lookup([[C];[#Headers]]; Parameters[What]; Parameters[Cost])
)
```

I want to have a formula that will cover new column if I add one. So, let's say I've added a column named `NEW`, so the formula should automatically pick it up and effectively work like this:

```
=sum(
    [A]*Lookup([[A];[#Headers]]; Parameters[What]; Parameters[Cost]);
    [B]*Lookup([[B];[#Headers]]; Parameters[What]; Parameters[Cost]);
    [C]*Lookup([[C];[#Headers]]; Parameters[What]; Parameters[Cost]);
    [NEW]*Lookup([[NEW];[#Headers]]; Parameters[What]; Parameters[Cost])
)
```

The `Parameters` table will of course include a row with value `NEW`

Comment: Can you give an example of the values in cost for these two items in your picture. I think item1 needs to be (50*4+5*100+1*150) right?

Comment: Will the columns in TableA always correspond to the rows in the Parameters?

Comment: Your question is not very clear because you are imagining syntax that you would like to have. It would be helpful to provide a real Excel formula that you hard-coded at the intersection of Cost and item1.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be (50*4+5*100+1*150) for item 1 then you can apply this formulae in cell B3 assuming that the word "cost is in cell B2

```
INDEX($B$7:$B$9,MATCH($C$2,$A$7:$A$9,0))*$C3+INDEX($B$7:$B$9,MATCH($D$2,$A$7:$A$9,0))*$D3+INDEX($B$7:$B$9,MATCH($E$2,$A$7:$A$9,0))*$E3
```

Comment: I want to lookup the correct product values by column names

Comment: Still not clear. Like I mentioned in the comment to your question. Give an example of the values that you expect

Answer (score 0):

If the parameters in tables `TableA` and `Parameters` are in the same order, then you can use the following in column `Cost`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(TRANSPOSE(TableA[@[A]:[C]])*Parameters[Cost])
```

Entered as array formula (i.e. type the formula then instead of pressing Enter, press Ctrl+Shift+Enter)

[image]

EDIT:

If the columns in TableA are not ordered, but those in Parameters are, then you can use the following (I'm not 100% sure it always works, but I've been testing a bit and it seems to work fine):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(TableA[@[A]:[C]]*LOOKUP(TableA[[#Headers],[A]:[C]],Parameters[What],Parameters[Cost]))
```

Doesn't need to be entered as array formula.

Comment: Columns' order from `TableA` will no match rows' order from `Params`. What you can assume is `Params` will be in ascending order - that's the reason for `Lookup` function

Comment: @SOReader Then, I doubt there's a shorter method. My suggestion in that case would either be to make sure TableA and Parameters have the same order of Parameters, or to use a second table as intermediate: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Gwr6.png

Comment: @SOReader Edited in another formula, which I believe solves the issue.

Comment: I've added more explanation. Please, have a look again. Hope this sheds some more light on the problem

Comment: @SOReader And what if instead of adding the column at the end, you insert it before the last column? E.g. If you insert a new column between B and C, and call it D, the formula above still works. In a real case scenario, you could put a dummy column at the end of the table, and always insert new columns before that one. Otherwise, it will be a long formula, but not unfeasible.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is amended to take account of your statement that the columns of TableA do not necessarily match entries in the rows of the Parameters table.

If you don't mind using macro code, you could define your own function to do the job:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function TotalCost(rItemCodes As Range, rCostTable As Range, rItemCounts As Range) As Double
    '// this function returns the total cost of an item using
    '// a lookup into a table of costs from a code, multiplying
    '// the item count by the corresponding cost

    Dim rItemCount As Range
    Dim rCost As Range
    Dim rCode As Range
    Dim rMatchingCode As Range

    '// Define the code list as the first column of the cost table
    Dim rCodeList As Range
    Set rCodeList = rCostTable.Columns(1)

    TotalCost = 0

    Dim ix As Integer

    '// Loop through every item code
    For ix = 1 To rItemCodes.Columns.Count
        Set rItemCount = rItemCounts.Cells(1, ix)
        Set rCode = rItemCodes.Cells(1, ix)
        Set rMatchingCode = Nothing

        On Error Resume Next

            '// Find the item that matches in the cost list
            Set rMatchingCode = rCodeList.Find(rCode.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)

            '// Check it was found, and calculate the additional cost
            If Not rMatchingCode Is Nothing Then
                Set rCost = rMatchingCode.Cells(1, 2)
                TotalCost = TotalCost + rItemCount.Value * rCost.Value
            End If

        On Error GoTo 0
    Next ix


End Function
```

If you named the table of costs in the parameters table, say, CostTable (range A8:B10 in your example), and the heading row of table A, say, CodeList (range C1:E1 in your example) then the formula in B2 would be `=TotalCost(CodeList,CostTable,C2:E2)`.

Comment: I'd rather don't use macros until it is absolutely necessary.

Comment: Fair enough, but macros used carefully can simplify in-cell formulas dramatically and make your spreadsheet easier to maintain.